# Right parameters for defrag on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-server-2012-r2, defragment

In Windows Server 2012 R2 I used the standard `dfrgui.exe` to turn the scheduled optimization on. After several months I looked at the Defrag UI again and noticed that drives were never optimized since I left the machine unattended. After I performed the optimization manually, last run time was updated.

I decided to look at the scheduler task that is responsible for the optimization and found that triggers for this task weren't set at all. Ok, I added trigger manually. Optimization should start at 03:00 every Wednesday ... but drives weren't optimized.

When I attempted to start Defrag UI again, it reported me, that some other software set optimization parameters and Defrag UI cannot be run (what for a nonsense!). Otherwise I could agree that Defrag UI resets the scheduler task to the original (not working) state and then I will be allowed to see Defrag UI (what for nonsense again!).

So, I found out that with the standard routines I will never be able to organize scheduled defragmentation, so I created my own task, 1:1 as the original task, but with my custom triggers. This time I had a scheduled task and no interference with Defrag UI. But drives still weren't optimized!

Then I looked at command line used to run the optimization. It was:

```
%windir%\system32\defrag.exe -c -h -k -g -$
```

When I ran this command line from console window, defrag.exe displayed its banner and exited immediately, without optimizing anything!

After some experimenting I found out, that it never optimizes, when any of the keys `-k` or `-g` is in the command line. So, the final command line that actually did optimize my HDDs is

```
%windir%\system32\defrag.exe -c -h -$
```

but SSD wasn't trimmed. It is shown as "20 days since last run".

Now I have several questions:

1. How to get SSD trimmed on a scheduled basis?
2. what do the keys `-k` or `-g` actually do? Is it Ok to run without these keys?

- /G Optimize the storage tiers on the specified volumes.
- /K Perform slab consolidation on the specified volumes.

Ok, I can read the help, but what are "storage tiers" and "slab"?

Comment: "When I attempted to start Defrag UI again, it reported me, that some other software set optimization parameters and Defrag UI cannot be run (what for a nonsense!). " doesn;t sound like nonsense to me. what did it say precisely?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/defrag - defrag parameters.

Comment: Tiers and slabs are related to Windows Storage Spaces AFAIK.